# How to nest JSON data?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I have a json object and I need to nest it so I can work with  it much better.

my json looks as follow:

```
[
  {
    "lat": null,
    "lng": null,
    "locationId": null
  },{
    "lat": null,
    "lng": null,
    "locationId": null
  }
]
```

and *I need to wrap it nest it and have the result as*:

```
{
  "number_returned": 2, //returns result_list count
  "data": {
    "result_list": [
      {
        "lat": null,
        "lng": null,
        "locationId": null
      },
      {
        "lat": null,
        "lng": null,
        "locationId": null
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: So what's your problem?

Comment: I need to nest the json body into "result_list" && "data" &&number_returned"

Comment: yes, but that's what you already did. If you mean using a program, it'd be nice to know what program or programming language, and what you tried so far

Comment: @Geoffroy no I haven't the code below is an example (of the end result)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the simple idea (in pseudo code) is to do this:

```
new_json = {
    "number_returned": old_json.length,
    "data": {
        "result_list": old_json
    }
}
```

assuming that `old_json` is a **string** containing JSON you have,
and `new_json` will be **string** with JSON you want to have;
the javascript to do all you need will look like this:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(old_json);
var result_obj = {
    "number_returned": obj.length,
    "data": {
        "result_list": obj
    }
}
var new_json = JSON.stringify(result_obj);
```

Comment: This assumes the JSON is already parsed, and does not stringify the resulting object back to JSON. See: [What is the difference between JSON and Object Literal Notation?](/q/2904131/3982562) If this is what OP is looking for than OP also mixes up JavaScript objects and JSON.

Comment: @3limin4t0r To be honest - I was aware that i mix object with json and i kind of did it on purpose. The question is not very clear what we talk about - so i answered with some kind of pseudo-code... but - well ...lets fix it

Comment: @3limin4t0r hope You are satisfied now? :) don't forget to mark my answer as useful ;)